# Problem IPV6 DNSMASQ with only DHCP/DNS servers (OpenWRT)

Tags: networking, configuration, openwrt, router, dnsmasq

I've set up DHCP ... and so far so good. The problem is when I try to connect a device. I did a test with Linux and each time it only sets me 1 DNS (**i have set two dns server in DHCP server**).
It also sets me other nameservers / searches that I have not set up on the openwrt DHCP server!

***PS. I have disabled the DNS of dnsmasq***

[image]

[image][image][image: enteenter image description herer image description here]
[image]

[image]

**How can I disable this thing?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you only have one DHCPd server on the network?  Extra DNS server IPs is pretty strange.

When a client makes a DHCP request it takes any answer it receives on the assumption that the LAN is secure. There is no prioritization. Which ever server answers first wins.

Comment: yes...Don't pay attention to that "192.168.2.1" which is my lan ... and in my lan I don't have the DHCP server. In the router network, however, I disabled DHCP ... so there should only be mine! So, where does that a come `nameserver fe80::d635:1dff:fe5d:74ab%wlan0` and `search homenet.telecomitalia.it` from?

Comment: The strange thing is that if I use **isc-dhcp-server** this doesn't happen! How is it possible? Is there any setting in dnsmasq?

Comment: Log Registry System Openwrt: `Tue Oct  4 01:30:31 2022 daemon.info dnsmasq[5678]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus UBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth cryptohash DNSSEC no-ID loop-detect inotify dumpfile`. How do I disable DHCPV6?